# Modify dynamically JSF snippets by h:commandlink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a h:commandlink control in page1. the control uses f:ajax to call to the following h:panelgroup :

I have a h:panelgroup control in page2 (a snippet), which has a ui:include within it.
I have a h:panelgroup control in page3 (a snippet), which has a ui:include within it.

Now according to the choices made on page1, I would like to switch the snippets by clicking on the h:commandlink control.

I have a BIG problem there: it seems that only if I click twice on the commandlink, only then the snippet changes - and not on one click.

I have tried to remove the f:ajax to render the panelgroup, and still it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two potential causes of this problem.

1. The `<f:ajax>` is fully re-rendering *another* `<h:form>` than where it is sitting in. This way the view state of the other form will get lost which would require invoking the action on the other form twice before it really get executed.

   The solution is to not re-render the other `<h:form>`, but only some container component in that form. E.g.

   ```
   <h:form id="otherForm">
       <h:panelGroup id="content">
           ...
       <h:panelGroup>
   </h:form>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <f:ajax render=":otherForm:content" />
   ```

   ---
2. When there's a `rendered` attribute on the `<h:commandLink>` or any of its parent components, then it *must* evaluate `true` during the apply request values phase of the postback request in order to get JSF to invoke the bean action associated with the `<h:commandLink>` during the invoke action phase of that request. Perhaps the bean is request scoped and/or some odd/illogical flow inside the bean caused that the `rendered` attribute is not properly been preserved.

   Best is to maintain those `rendered` conditions in a `@ViewScoped` bean and let its action methods return `void` or `null` so that the bean lives as long as you're interacting with the same view. Change the `rendered` conditions during action methods only and not inside setters/getters or something.

Comment: It seems that it was the second issue that has caused the problem.
Something in the request flow made the getter raise before the setter... It made me somewhat confused for quite a while.

Comment: Getters/setters should have the sole task to return and set the property, not to do some business job. There the listener and action methods are for.

Comment: If I save the link string of the snippet and change it using getters/setters, I don't have the ability to make changes in the flow... you gave me good a direction for where the problem started... the solution was changing the postback method from POST to GET, that way I used another ActionListner before Getter/Setter logic started. Thank you @BalusC